# Image list with checkbox in ASP.NET Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I have a list of images and need to allow user to check/uncheck each of them when posting from a Razor view.

```
public class Image
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Sku { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
    }

public class ImagesViewModel {
    public  Image Image { get; set; }
    public  bool Checked { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in Razor view I have `@model List<ImagesViewModel>`.
I wonder if this is the best approach to this or there is some better solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I like to have a parent class:

```
pulic class ImageListViewModel
{
  public List<ImageViewModel> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Having the list directly is fine, but a root viewmodel then encapsulates the entire data for the view and allows you to add additional properties in the future.  Plus, it's easier to use collection-based references like:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Images[0].Checked)
```

It's not wrong to expose a list directly; it's just that sometimes you quickly find the need for additional properties to add to the ImageListViewModel...